# Parâmetros dos labels em PrintPage

Tags: c#, label

Quais os parâmetros possíveis para definir a impressão de labels:
O código que estou a usar é o seguinte:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(label_nota_entrega.Text, new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new PointF(550, 50));
```

É possível colocar uma cor de fundo no label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar `LabelTeste.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;` ou ainda se preferir seguir na linha de desenhar tudo na tela. Você pode usar junto ao **DrawString** o **DrawRectangle** e o **FillRectangle**.

```
int LarguraRetangulo = 150;
int AlturaRetangulo = 20;

e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.LightGray), 0, 0, LarguraRetangulo, AlturaRetangulo);
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, 0, 0, LarguraRetangulo, AlturaRetangulo);

e.Graphics.DrawString(label_nota_entrega.Text, new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Se não estou em erro só precisa fazer algo deste género:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(label_nota_entrega.Text, label_nota_entrega.BackColor = Color.Red, new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new PointF(550, 50));
```